# Excel - using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to using macro, so thought I could ask for some help in simple query like this...I am trying to run a VBA where:

If D5 is blank, then clearcontent in E5 & If E5 is blank, then clearcontents in F5
repeats this all the way through D100/E100/F100.

Hope this clarifies it.

Thanks!

Edit: in response to 'make an effort to try to resolve it first', this was my initial coding (help from googling also) but it only looked at one row which is why I raised the question

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D5")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("E5").ClearContents

End If

  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5")) Is Nothing Then
   Range("F5").ClearContents

 End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Note: I want to use a macro since these cells have dropdown list function on them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't a code writing service. Please make an effort (which includes searching for and reading existing questions here) to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done that, you can make an effort to write the code. If you run into difficulties, you can then explain what you're trying to do, include the *relevant portions* of the code you've written, and ask a specific question, and we can try to help. Good luck.

Comment: why are you checking E5? you just cleared it. if D5 is blank clear E5:F5 should do what you want .... your question is not completely clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim n As Long

    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        If IsEmpty(Cells(Target.Row, 4)) Then
               Range("E" & Target.Row).ClearContents
               Range("F" & Target.Row).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: omg thanks this is what I wanted (looking at it independently row by row)! :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why you would want to do this, since it is basically going to clear every cell after the first cell it finds to be empty.  But hey, I don't know your project.  Here is a quick and dirty way to do it.

```
For x = 5 to 100
  If IsEmpty(cells(5, x)) then
    Cells(5, x+1).Clear
Next
```